# Basic unit testing for ArcGIS 10.0 Java Add-in

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, java, add-in

I've been assigned the task of translating an old ArcGIS VBA script into a Java add-in. I finished the rough translation of the code, now I'm starting the debug process. The first unit test I want to set up is the creation of an Application object. I'm getting the error "0x80040154 - Class not registered".

Any ideas?

I'm a very novice programmer.

Here's the code for my test:

```
@Test
public void testOnClick() {
    try {
        EngineInitializer.initializeEngine();
        AoInitialize ao = new AoInitialize();
        ao.initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeArcInfo);
        IApplication app = new Application();
        assertNotNull(app);
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("UnknownHostException: " + e.toString());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```